# My shape moved but will pause for a while

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I've programmed a simple 'game' using JavaFX. It's basically a rectangle that moves left and right. The problem is when a key is hold down, the rectangle moved (good) but it pauses for a while before it moves continually. Any solution for this?

P.S I'm new to this site >_<

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application
{
    protected static SimpleIntegerProperty sint_speed = new SimpleIntegerProperty(1);
    protected static double dbl_playerW = 140,dbl_playerH = 20;
    protected static SimpleDoubleProperty sdbl_playerX = new  SimpleDoubleProperty(130),sdbl_playerY = new SimpleDoubleProperty(360);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stg_main)
    {
        Group grp_main = new Group();

        Label lbl_spd = new Label();
        lbl_spd.textProperty().bind(sint_speed.asString());
        Button btn_increaseSpd = new Button(">");
        btn_increaseSpd.setOnAction(e->
        {
            sint_speed.set(sint_speed.intValue() + 1);
        });
        Button btn_decreaseSpd = new Button("<");
        btn_decreaseSpd.setOnAction(e->
        {
            if(sint_speed.intValue() > 0)
            {
                sint_speed.set(sint_speed.intValue() - 1);
            }
        });

        HBox h1 = new HBox(10);
        h1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        h1.getChildren().addAll(btn_decreaseSpd,lbl_spd,btn_increaseSpd);
        grp_main.getChildren().add(h1);

        subRoute_Player(grp_main);

        Scene scn_main = new Scene(grp_main,400,400);
        scn_main.setOnKeyPressed(e->
        {
            if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT)
            {
                sdbl_playerX.set(sdbl_playerX.doubleValue() - sint_speed.intValue());
            }
            else if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT)
            {
                sdbl_playerX.set(sdbl_playerX.doubleValue() + sint_speed.intValue());
            }
        });

        stg_main.setScene(scn_main);
        stg_main.setResizable(false);
        stg_main.show();
    }

    protected static void subRoute_Player(Group grp_rcvd)
    {
        Rectangle rct_player = new Rectangle();

        rct_player.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        rct_player.setWidth(dbl_playerW);
        rct_player.setHeight(dbl_playerH);
        rct_player.translateXProperty().bind(sdbl_playerX);
        rct_player.translateYProperty().bind(sdbl_playerY);

        grp_rcvd.getChildren().add(rct_player);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: we are not mindreaders. please post the relevant code.

Comment: Most likely that is caused by the usual key press behaviour - continously press any key in any editor, and you will see that the letter is typed, followed by a short pause, and only then it is typed continously. Most likely, you need to define an event handler for `onKeyReleased()` and then, in `onKeyPressed`, start the movement if not already started, and in `onKeyReleased()` stop the movement

Comment: By the way, your code as it is posted does not compile - please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @AndreasFester As for SSCCE, please see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283437/mcve-vs-sscce-battle MCVE is an SO specific version of SSCCE and hence is preferred.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Thanks - need to update my SO comment boilerplates :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what @McKevin posted, you can use a `TranslateTransition` to do the actual movement. Simply start the transition in the `onKeyPressed()` handler and stop it in the `onKeyReleased()` handler. The following code fragments show how this can be done for one direction (you still need to add the distinction between left and right and add handling for the corner cases when your player has reached some limit):

```
...
private Rectangle rct_player;
private TranslateTransition transTransition;
private boolean isMoving = false;
...

    // Create the translate transition for the rectangle
    transTransition = new TranslateTransition(new Duration(75000), rct_player);
    transTransition.setToY(0);
    transTransition.setToX(1500);
    transTransition.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
    transTransition.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

    scn_main.setOnKeyPressed(e-> {
        if (!isMoving) {
            transTransition.play();
            isMoving = true;
        }
    });
    scn_main.setOnKeyReleased(e -> {
        transTransition.stop(); 
        isMoving = false;
    });
...
```

See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/TranslateTransition.html

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with how the OnKeyPressed event is being fired. To visualize this, you can hold any key on your keyboard and you'll notice how the first character comes out and pauses for a good while being the rest of the stream comes out.

To solve this, use a boolean flag:

```
isMovingLeft = false;
isMovingRight = false;

if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT){
     //instead of doing this:
     //sdbl_playerX.set(sdbl_playerX.doubleValue() - sint_speed.intValue());
     isMovingLeft = true;
}

OnKeyPressed(){
   if left is pressed:
       set isMovingLeft to true;
   if right is pressed:
       set isMovingRight to true;
}

onKeyReleased(){
   if left is released:
       set isMovingLeft to false;
   if right is pressed:
       set isMovingRight to false; 
}

//maingameloop i.e: handle method in JavaFX
handle(){
    if(isMovingLeft){
        //apply move left logic
    }
    if(isMovingRight){
        //apply move right logic
    }
}
```